# CSS Will not change ANY colors

Tags: html, css, colors

This is my first post and I have found many solutions on this website, but this is the first time I could not research and find the issue.

I am having a terrible time trying to change the colors of this webpage I am designing for my new business. I am unable to change any of the colors in the style sheet. For example I am trying to change the color of where it says Mr Fix All on the main page from #fff to #FF4500, after inspecting the elements I have tracked the style back to class="carousel-title" so in my layout.css I goto the Carousel-title and changed it from #fff to #ff4500 and nothing happens.

I have gone as far as changing the code for the color white to FF4500 and remove all #fff from the entire document and the color still wont change.

After some research of this issue I saw other people had anchors that "over ride" the colors, but there are not anchors, this is just a heading so I cannot find out where this color is calling from.

I even looked at the Div tag above carousel-center which has no color tags at all. I haven't been able to change a single color on this website so I am very confused!

Any assistance would be great, this is the only thing stopping me from completing this page, I cannot read half the words because they are all white.... or very light grey. I want to make all the words either FF4500 or darker gray like the heading is at the top.

http://www.mrfixalltampa.com

lol I suck I cannot figure out how to put the code this website is throwing syntax errors I cannot believe it!

Comment: Please post your code so other can help you. Read [https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea to change the color for the carousel-title class in your example.
As a standard practice don't edit the layout.css or other plugin files. Instead, you should create another custom CSS file.

So, for your example to change the carousel title "Mr. Fix All" color, you could create a custom.css file having your style overrides like below

```
.carousel-title {
    color:#FF4500
}
```

and add it to your index.html as the last stylesheet included, as shown below

```
  <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="vendor/swiper/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="css/layout.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <!-- Custom Stylesheet -->
  <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: Serving it last is important, otherwise the plugin sheet will take priority.

Comment: I apologize for not putting code, i saw other posts while researching this where people asked for the website URL.

*/

Comment: Why can i not just change the base code instead of making more css files? this is so confusing I don't understand where its calling from. If I am changing the wrong spot where do i need to change it?

I cannot figure out how to upload my code the website is giving me errors about spacing this is frustrating

Comment: I think i understand your solution, I am going to try that now, Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Sir, that worked, i guess that is an easy solution, but it does not really answer the root cause for me. irrelevant, the result is there, THANKS!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please consider marking it as accepted.